# Drawing a Closed Curve from given points

Tags: graphics

I have the following points:

```
aa={{238.5, 394.5}, {195.5, 441.5}, {219.5, 397.5}, {216.5, 
 398.5}, {246.5, 397.5}, {265.5, 476.5}, {275.5, 450.5}, {273.5, 
 435.5}, {274.5, 461.5}, {212.5, 447.5}, {221.5, 457.5}}
```

Now, I want to draw a closed curve from those line. So I used the following code:

```
Graphics[{{Blue, Point[aa]}, JoinedCurve[Line[aa], CurveClosed -> True]}]
```

But, it gives me curve like this:

[image]

I want the curve like this way:

[image]

Please let me know, how to do it. And, I want it to do automatically, not point by point. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the above method doesn't always work. Here is an alternative:

```
aa = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
Graphics[Line[aa[[Last[FindShortestTour[aa]]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ah, didn't mean to sound competitive - just meant as an alternative! I am always learning from your answers anyway +1 :)

Comment: Don't worry, I was joking

Comment: it looks like a cute cat

Comment: This also guarantees the curve is closed which is a plus

Answer (score 9):

```
curve = FindCurvePath[aa]
ListLinePlot[aa[[curve[[1]]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Why not directly use `ListCurvePathPlot`?

```
ListCurvePathPlot@aa
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that ListCurvePathPlot doesn't guarantee that the curve is closed.

Comment: @AdrianSmith Yeah, actually it's mentioned in the **Details and Options** of the document: `ListCurvePathPlot` can generate disconnected curves in certain cases. But it at least works for OP's case.