# Custom interpolation algorithm

Tags: plotting, interpolation

Suppose I have a list to create a list density plot, the list format is:

```
list = {{0.5, 0.5, 0.0}, {-0.5, 0.5, 1.0}, {1.0, -0.45, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}
```

The size of the list is about 10^5 elements

The plot will show a point or nothing at all. The real data produces this picture:

[image]

My goal is to make solid lines so that the shapes look smooth, however, I also need a list containing all the points that make the smoothed out picture. Since I know the distance of the mesh, I was thinking about a procedure that would go through the whole grid searching for neighboring points and if there exists a point with `{x, y, 1}` would fill in the blanks. I'm stuck in the criterion to use for this though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any chance you can share the actual data?

Comment: I can, but I dont what the best method would be. I didnt want to post a huge array here.

Comment: You can use e.g. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or similar services to share a text-only version of your array.

Comment: Closely related: [(70102)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70102/121). Somewhat related: [(109357)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109357/121), [(111460)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111460/121), [(118132)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118132/121), [(136181)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136181/121)

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/8u6i5y9e6rgb5/Data

Comment: Above you can find a CSV file of the array.

Comment: I maybe mistaken, but I think I've seen this exact question with that same graph before somewhere on here. (I'm looking for it right now)

Comment: I posted a similar question a few weeks back, however, I think is a better question or a better approach. I was looking to maybe doing something with image processing, but since I need the list of point its not a good approach. I might delete the previous question.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler approach might be to work with one of those features at a time, and in 2D, since the third dimension is simply a toggle indicator here. For instance, consider `ListPlot@Select[data, Apply[-0.3 < #1 < 0.3 && 0.2 < #2 < 0.5 && #3 == 1. &]][[All, ;; 2]]` that returns [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BJzEZ.png).

Comment: I was working on something similar, using the clustering feature. I will update if I can make it work.

Comment: For reference, the previous question is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151724/extracting-the-contour-lines-from-an-image

Comment: @MichaelE2 Should I delete the previous question or link this question there? Im not sure what the procedure should be for this.

Comment: When a question is based on another post, usually the user (edits the question and) puts a link to the previous post in the question. -- In this case, some user(s) seem to think they're the same question.  Normally the procedure is to mark the newer question a duplicate of the older question, but here they've done the reverse.  Perhaps the best thing to do is to click the "flag" button and indicate you think the two Q&A should be merged. (It needs moderator intervention to perform the action, but since you're the author of each, they will probably do it.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imported your posted data:

```
raw = Import["array1.CSV"];
```

Then selected one of the features, and reduced it to two-dimensional, since the third dimension is uniformly equal to $1$ for the points constituting the feature:

```
single = Cases[raw, {a_, b_, 1.} :> {a, b} /; (-0.2 < a < 0.2 && 0.2 < b)];

ListPlot[
 single,
 PlotRange -> {0.2, 0.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: plot]

I isolate the oval feature manually:

```
oval = Cases[single, {a_, b_} /; (-0.07 < a < 0.07 && 0.35 < b < 0.472)];

ListPlot[
  oval,
  PlotRange -> {0.39, 0.48}, AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: oval points]

Then I fit an axis-aligned ellipse to it, by generating an appropriate squared distance function to be minimized, then making the assumption that the abscissa of the center is $0$, which seems reasonable given the symmetry of the system, and imposing reasonable constraints on the other parameters obtained from inspection of the graph:

```
obj[a_, b_, xc_, yc_] = Total[
   Simplify[
     SquaredEuclideanDistance[{#1, #2}, (#1 - xc)^2/a^2 + (#2 - yc)^2/b^2 - 1] & @@@ oval,
     _ ∈ Reals
   ]
 ];

minPars = FindMinimum[{obj[a, b, 0, yc], 0.42 < yc < 0.46}, {{a, 0.5}, {b, 0.5}, {yc, 0.44}}]

(* {14.2803, {a -> 0.0518811, b -> 0.0312114, yc -> 0.439966}} *)
```

It's a pretty good fit, despite the few stray points we had to tolerate:

```
cplot = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[((x - 0)^2/a^2 + (y - yc)^2/b^2 == 1) /. First@Rest@minPars],
   {x, -0.08, 0.08}, {y, 0.4, 0.48},
   Epilog -> Point[oval], AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: fit oval and points]

Now, we can extract the line shape from the contour plot results:

```
ovalLine = First@Cases[Normal@cplot, _Line, Infinity];
```

---

I then carefully select the points at the periphery of your feature, through somewhat laborious manual filtering:

```
rdf = RegionDistance[ovalLine];

externalPoints = Join[
   DeleteCases[single, pt_ /; rdf[pt] < 0.00715],
   Complement[
     Select[single, #[[2]] > 0.4713 &],
     MinimalBy[Select[single, #[[2]] > 0.4713 &], Abs@#[[1]] &, 2]
   ]
 ];

Graphics@Point@externalPoints
```

[image: external]

I then use the fantastic `alphaShapes2DC` function proposed by [RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88769/27951), to generate a "concave hull" of those points:

```
alphaShapes2DC[externalPoints, .10]
```

[image: alpha shape]

In fact, I will turn the 2D region returned by that function into a boundary mesh region, with some formatting for appearances only:

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    alphaShapes2DC[externalPoints, .10],
    MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Directive[Thick, Red]},
    PlotTheme -> "Lines"
  ];
```

[image: formatted alpha shape]

---

Let's now put it all together:

```
Show[reg, Graphics[{Thick, Red, ovalLine}]]
```

[image: both lines]

And here's a comparison to the original points:

```
Show[reg, Graphics[{Thick, Red, ovalLine, Black, Point[single]}]]
```

[image: with points]

---

And finally let's generate polygons and rotate them around the axis to generate the final shape:

```
allShapes = NestList[
   GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[2 Pi/3, {0, 0}]] &,
   MeshPrimitives[reg, 2],
   2
 ];

allOvals = NestList[
   GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[2 Pi/3, {0, 0}]] &,
   Polygon @@ ovalLine,
   2
 ];

Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], allOvals, allShapes}]
```

[image: final]

Comment: In the obj function, xc is not used cause it's set to 0 in the formula itself, correct?

Comment: @GiovanniBaez Yes that's correct. That's a bit muddled in fact. It must have been an intermediate version that I copied. I meant to have `xc` explicitly it in the formula in the definition of `obj`. I will clean that up.

Comment: Could I use the final form of AllShapes and AllOvals to create a RegionDistanceFunction ? I now have an array and wish to delete points within a certain distance of the lines.

Comment: @GiovanniBaez Something could be certainly cobbled together, but not right out of the box, because the idea seems ambiguous to me. For instance, would you like such a function to return the minimum distance of a point from any one of the three shapes in the list, or the average distance from all three, or the sum of the distances...? You would need to define that more precisely.

Comment: For the region without the oval I used RegionBoundary to define the boundary line and combined with the RegionDistance for each part managed to take out points in an array within a certain distance of the lines. This has been very helpful.

Comment: @GiovanniBaez I am very glad to hear that. My approach was rather kludgy; I am glad you could improve on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63185/discussion-between-giovanni-baez-and-marcob).